# How to render HTML in .jsp file

Tags: java, html, jsp

I passing some data as object from java to .jsp file and I want to organize it in html table. The problem I am having is that the html code is displayed as raw text so in short if I put

```
<h1> hello </h1>
```

in .jsp it just reads as "`<h1> hello </h1>`" not as "hello". Is there a way to render the tags without displaying them?
[How it looks right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXKOY.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and be sure to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please show the code from your jsp file.

Comment: Added picture of how it shows right now. It bascially just renders what is inside "" tags. I want it to actualyl show text Hello as it would appear in .html page.

Comment: You should put `jstl c:out tag` within `html tag` like: `<h1><c:out value="hello" escapeXml="false"/></h1>`

Comment: [Result](https://imgur.com/a/eQoNETC) Is still doesn't work this way.

Comment: Please look at the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put `jstl c:out tag` within `html tag`. Also, you have to declare `html, head, body tags` to define `html` structure.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
    <h1><c:out value="hello" escapeXml="false"/></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Result](https://imgur.com/a/RMvaPok) I have done as advised but it still doesn't render html. I have a feeling jsp is not rendering html. I am sorry if I miss understood this but I'm still quite fresh to the idea.

Comment: Did you try in different browsers like Chrome, and can you please check the header response returned by your server?

Comment: I did try. My question is. Does JSP actually renders the html code or should I read .jsp result and read is in html page?

Comment: Yes, JSP pages can render HTML.

Comment: I went for another option. I passed json of my data to jquery. Jquery decode the json and put into array. Array later is used to create table of all data in front end. Thanks!

Comment: oh okay, perfect.